# make a list of different random integers less than ten

Tags: c++, random

I want to generate a list of random integers less than  10 witch are not the same ( different integers )for example ( 0,3,1,5,8).
but the code that I have written has a problem and first two integers always are the same.
that would be great if you code tell me the mistake of my code or offer me another way to do that.

```
vector<int> rand_list(10, 11); //there is ten integers of 11   
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // here we make 5 different integers
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int r = rand() % 10;
    int check = 0;
    for (check; check <= i; check++)
    {
       if (r == rand_list[check])
       {
         srand(time(NULL));
         r = rand() % 10;
         check = 0;//I think this line don't force the second loop for to start again.
       }
    }
    rand_list[i] = r;
}
```

here I expect rand_list with 5 different integers and the other items must be 11 but first two integers are always the same!

Comment: You probably want to seed it once, before you start.

Comment: [You may find `std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) useful here if the assignment requirements have not forbidden it. And if they have, steal the idea.

Comment: You can also simply fill a vector ``v`` with ``0..10``, then, 5 times, pick a random index in ``0..v.size()-1``, add the value at that index to your result, then remove that element from the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `srand()` multiple times. `time()` has seconds precision, so calling `srand()` multiple times within the same second with `time()` as the seed will cause `rand()` to return the same number each time, which is not what you want to happen.  Call `srand()` only once, such as at program startup.

Even better, don't use the C runtime's random number generator at all. Use a standard C++ random number generator instead.

As for your algorithm, a simpler solution would be to put sequential numbers 0-9 into an array, then run a loop that generates a random index into that array and removes that element to put into your vector, repeating until all of the  array elements are exhausted, eg:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());

std::vector<int> rand_list(10);

int numbers[10];
std::generate_n(numbers, 10, [n = 0]() mutable { return n++; });
int avail = 10;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, avail-1);  
    int r = dis(gen);
    rand_list[i] = numbers[r];
    std::copy(&numbers[r+1], &numbers[avail], &numbers[r]);
    --avail;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/DuBu0W)

Or even simpler, you can use the standard `std::shuffle()` algorithm instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());

std::vector<int> rand_list(10);
std::generate_n(rand_list.begin(), 10, [n = 0]() mutable { return n++; });
std::shuffle(rand_list.begin(), rand_list.end(), gen);
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/zVAxCI)

Answer (score 0):

Use `srand()` only once at the start of your program.
Then, an easy way to get distinct random numbers from a range of values is, 
to draw a random number from the set of numbers not used yet.

- Fill your set of numbers (e.g. into a vector).
- (repeat e.g. 5 times): generate a random index into your set of numbers.
  Then print the number at that index.
  Then remove the number at that index from your set of unused numbers.

This way, you need no retries and checks if the number has already been used.
Since `std::vector<T>::erase(const_iter it)` is not `O(1)`, `std::vector<T>` might not be the optimal data structure for that. Optimally, you would need a data structure which allows to index in `O(1)` and to erase in `O(1)`.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    using UI16Vec = std::vector<uint16_t>;
    UI16Vec numbers;
    srand(time(NULL));
    // Fill in your range of numbers.
    numbers.reserve(10);
    for(  uint16_t i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
         numbers.push_back(i);
    }
    // Pick and remove from numbers.
    for( size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    {
         size_t index = rand() % numbers.size();
         printf("%d: %d\n", i, numbers[index] );
         numbers.erase(numbers.cbegin() + index);
    }
    return 0;
}
```